# CORS issue with Wordpress login inside iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, cors

I am trying to embed a Wordpress site into a Trello card, so it's in a page with the `trello.com` domain.

When i try to log in to the WP site through the iframe, i get an `HTTP 302` redirect response due to the CORS settings, but i think i did set the CORS headers properly so i cannot understand where is the issue.

I have also disabled the caching from `wp-config.php`

```
define('WP_CACHE', false);
define('CACHE_PLUGIN', false);
```

And i have tried navigating in incognito mode. Same error.
Any hint please?

These are the response headers from the login page, when i just load it from the iframe:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: max-age=7200
cf-edge-cache: cache,platform=wordpress
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 16605
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' trello.com
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 16 Apr 2023 12:35:30 GMT
expires: Sun, 16 Apr 2023 14:35:28 GMT
server: nginx/1.21.6
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-endurance-cache-level: 2
x-nginx-cache: WordPress
x-server-cache: false
```

These are the request headers, when i POST the login form:

```
:authority: <stripped>
:method: POST
:path: <stripped>
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,it;q=0.8
cache-control: max-age=0
content-length: 143
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
origin: <stripped>
referer: <stripped>
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Microsoft Edge";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"
sec-fetch-dest: iframe
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/112.0.1722.39
```

This is the response i see from the browser DevTools:

```
Method: POST
Status code: 302
Referrer criteria: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

And these the response headers:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: *
access-control-allow-origin: *
cache-control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
cf-edge-cache: cache,platform=wordpress
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self' trello.com
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Sun, 16 Apr 2023 12:45:06 GMT
expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
location: <stripped>
server: Apache
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_f05ed8f4e8683060ab52e6a34e8180cf=<stripped>
set-cookie: wordpress_sec_f05ed8f4e8683060ab52e6a34e8180cf=<stripped>
set-cookie: wordpress_logged_in_f05ed8f4e8683060ab52e6a34e8180cf=<stripped>
set-cookie: po_assigned_roles[0]=subscriber; path=/
x-endurance-cache-level: 2
x-nginx-cache: WordPress
x-redirect-by: WordPress
```

Comment: You may want to [enable CORS in your NGINX configuration](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Comment: @Jamie_D We have shared hosting, so i guess the provider has to enable it, right? Or can it be done from cPanel?

Comment: The requests that you show us are _not_ CORS requests, which you can observe by the absence of any `Origin` headers. The `Access-Control-*` headers are therefore irrelevant. And a 302 redirection response is what I would expect after a successful logon. A problem could be the `SameSite` attributes on the Wordpress cookies (or their absence), but you have stripped out that information. Also, these cookies are likely to be considered 3rd-party by your browser and therefore blocked.